# How to handle the content part in AJAX page switching in PWA?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, progressive-web-apps

I have zero experience in native apps, which might help with this question.

Since service worker caches everything so nicely, then I don't see any reason why I should render the entire webpage again when the page gets switched (link gets clicked.) So I will switch only the content, use history pushstate to change the URL and change the title. I have that part figured out.

Problem is, I cannot find any resources that would support either of the two content load ideas I have:

1. Load center content **via AJAX with HTML**.
2. Load center content **as data only** and render the HTML on-the-fly in JS.

First method would be fairly straight forward, but would mean that the payload would be bigger.

Second seems much more advanced, but would mean that HTML templates have to be in the JS somehow already? I also have a feeling, that there is a method somewhere in here.. that would allow to open the heavily cached page (lets say the article page) and replace the (text) contents. But as I said, I cannot find any resources to wager the cons and pros or give any reliable information on PWA AJAX page switching.

Any credible information on this matter would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
I have kept reading and researching on this matter, but sadly there is no clear indication on how to handle dynamic content over AJAX. Whether I should parse the JSON data from AJAX to HTML in JS or send it already as HTML from the backend.

To add in favour to second option. I have figured out, that my theory had somewhat weight to it. If I use [pure.js](https://pure-js.com/) to pull a HTML template from hidden [template tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp) and generate the HTML on the fly from JSON over AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

you make it so complicated can we take a look at your code please?!

if you mean retrieving data from database by ajaxthen all what when you need is a jquery plugin

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var contentData1 = document.getElementById('contentData1');
  $(function() {

    $.post("pathToPHP.php",{contentData1: contentData1},function(data){
        $("#container").html(data);
    });
});
```

and the pathToPHP.php file should retrieve the data you want

```
echo "";
```

Comment: The code is irrelevant. Question is the method of which is more suited for PWA AJAX page switching. Your answer doesn't respond to neither of the methods. Also why are you doing `document.getElementById('contentData1')` if you are already using jQuery, you could just `$('#contentData1')`. And you should pass your backend data by as json not just echo.

Comment: if you detect that so you don't need any help.